# Script to compare two XML files attribute by attribute

Tags: python, regex, xml

XML1:

```
<string name ="abc">Un problème pour changer de chaîne </string>
<string name ="def">Est-ce que vous voyez votre%1$s?</string>
```

XML2:

```
<string name ="abc">How are you?</string>
<string name ="def">Can you see your %1$s?</string>
```

place holder : %1$s

Need to find if both values have same count of the placeholders.

I converted the xml to dict and then tried using a static list of placeholders to compare string.Issue :In different languages the placeholders are clubbed with the word.

how can i do it using regular expression in python?

All possible placeholders :
%s
%1s
%1$s
%2$s
%3$s
%4$s
%1$d

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you want to map `Can you see your` to `Est-ce que vous voyez votre` based on the fact that they both have the same placeholder? What would you do with the values? If you need to match the placeholder, it would be `%[1-4]?\$?(s|d)`

Comment: Need to count and check if both have equal number of placeholders or not.